# Algoritmo que seleciona os N maiores números, soma eles e depois subtrai pelo restante de números menores que sobrou

Tags: python

Estou criando um algoritmo e preciso que ele selecione os 11 maiores números da lista e diminua pelo restante de números que sobrou.

exemplo:
input 13 (8 5 11 13 15 3 12 14 5 12 4 5 16) (digitados os n números, você seleciona os 11 maiores, soma eles e depois diminui pelo restante de números que sobrou (os menores números que sobraram depois dos 11 maiores)

A imagem a seguir deixará mais claro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
no primeiro input a lógica foi: 16+15+14+13+12+12+11+8+5+5+5 = 116 - 3 - 4 = 109
Meu código até agora foi esse:

```
n = int(input())
jogadores = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
jogadores.sort(reverse=True)
print(jogadores)
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Basta classificar descendentemente a lista, somar a fatia dos 11 primeiros elemento e do resultado subtrair a soma da fatia do 12 elemento ao último.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma maneira simples de fazer é utilizando o fatiamento de listas do Python.

O código fica da seguinte maneira:

```python
n = int(input())
jogadores = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
jogadores.sort(reverse=True)
soma1 = sum(jogadores[:11])
soma2 = sum(jogadores[11:])
print(soma1 - soma2)
```

Com o fatiamento é possível retornar de forma simples apenas partes de uma lista. Neste caso fatiamos a lista ordenada pegando os 11 primeiros elementos para a soma, e depois pegamos os demais elementos para subtrair.

Comment: No código de exemplo atual, terá o seguinte erro se tentar rodar, pois não existe um argumento nomeado de `reversejop`: `TypeError: 'reversejop' is an invalid keyword argument for sort()`

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Você sabe o motivo da linha `n = int(input())` estar no código?

Comment: @Ruan basta apagar o 'jop' e deixar apenas o reverse no código.

Comment: @JosueCosta é importante manter a qualidade das postagens no SO, por isso apontei o problema. Como o autor da pergunta sabe sobre o uso do `reverse`, o ideal é que o autor da resposta corrija o código e, se possível, adicione referências para que outras pessoas no futuro também possam se beneficiar dela.

Comment: Apenas corrigi e validei a edição que estava em analise. Mas tem coisa estranha, se é necessário ler de antemão a quantidade de inteiros que serão inseridos com `n = int(input())` então essa leitura `jogadores = [int(x) for x in input().split()]` provavelmente não vai funcionar pois é grande a chance da entrada não ser delimitada por espaços e sim por quebras de linha consecutivas aos dados, provavelmente vindas dum autômato de teste de uma plataforma de desafios onde provavelmente `n` é o número de entradas que terá que contar antes de iniciar os cálculos.